# Azure ratecard api filter by currency example

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure

I want to get the price of a resource according to its usage, for this, I am trying `azure ratecard API`. I am using python SDKs provided by Azure and here is the link for azure ratecard APIs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-commerce/azure.mgmt.commerce.operations.ratecardoperations?view=azure-python

problem is, we need to pass filter as an argument but I do not know how to pass values in the filter. I know we can use offer id, currency, locale, region for the filter, but **how to use them in ratecard api?**

Here is what I am trying

```
from azure.mgmt.commerce import UsageManagementClient

ratecardclient = UsageManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
ratecard = ratecardclient.rate_card.get(filter=???)
```

What I have tried in filter

```
ratecard = ratecardclient.rate_card.get("OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-0003P' and Currency eq 'INR' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'US'")

ratecard = ratecardclient.rate_card.get(filter="OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-0003P' and Currency eq 'INR' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'US'")
```

The error that I am getting from the above filters

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gsc/PycharmProjects/GsGit_Azure_cot/Azure/ADALAuth.py", line 375, in <module>
    ratecard = ratecardclient.rate_card.get("OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-0003P' and Currency eq 'INR' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'US'")
  File "C:\Users\gsc-30310\PycharmProjects\env_python3.6.8_v1\lib\site-packages\azure\mgmt\commerce\operations\rate_card_operations.py", line 94, in get
    raise models.ErrorResponseException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.mgmt.commerce.models.error_response.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Bad Request'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried it but looking at the documentation and the [`source code`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-mgmt-commerce/azure/mgmt/commerce/operations/rate_card_operations.py#L76), I believe you would need to specify OData filter string. Please try something like as filter string:

```
OfferDurableId eq '{OfferDurableId}' and Currency eq '{Currency}' and Locale eq '{Locale}' and RegionInfo eq '{RegionInfo}'
```

So your code would be:

```
from azure.mgmt.commerce import UsageManagementClient

ratecardclient = UsageManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
ratecard = ratecardclient.rate_card.get(filter="OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-0003p' and Currency eq 'INR' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'US'")
```

Comment: hi, I tried `ratecard = ratecardclient.rate_card.get(filter="OfferDurableId eq 0003P and Currency eq INR and Locale eq Central US and RegionInfo eq US")
` but I am getting `Operation returned an invalid status code 'Bad Request'`

Comment: Please try `OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-0003p' and Currency eq 'INR' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'US'`. See here for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/mt219004(v%3dazure.100)#request.

Comment: hi, I have tried `ratecard = ratecardclient.rate_card.get(filter="OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-0003P' and Currency eq 'INR' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'US'")
` this but still I am getting same `bad request error`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your support, the code is working now. I miss understood ` RegionInfo`, it is the region where you bought you subscription, so for me, it is `IN` India but I was putting ` RegionInfo` value 'US' because I thought it is related to `locale`.

Answer (score 1):

From the unitests:

```
    # OfferDurableID: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/offer-details/
    rate = self.commerce_client.rate_card.get(
        "OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-0062P' and Currency eq 'USD' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'US'"
    )
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-mgmt-commerce/tests/test_mgmt_commerce.py

Comment: hi, I am using pay-as-you-go subscription so my `OfferDurableId` is 'MS-AZR-0003P'. I have tried `ratecard = ratecardclient.rate_card.get("OfferDurableId eq 'MS-AZR-0003P' and Currency eq 'INR' and Locale eq 'en-US' and RegionInfo eq 'US'")
` but getting `azure.mgmt.commerce.models.error_response.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Bad Request'`

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. this code is also working,  I was using `RegionInfo` value 'US' because i thought it is ending  2 digit code of 'locale`, but it is 'IN' in my case because my subscription is bought in `India`.